# The real vector spaces $C[0,1]$ and $C[1,2]$ are isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Write $C[a,b]$ for the real vector space of all continuous functions $[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}.$

I need to show that the infinite-dimensional vector spaces $C[0,1]$ and $C[1,2]$ are isomorphic.

My idea is to define a map $\theta:C[0,1]\to C[1,2]$ like this:

For any $f \in C[0,1],$ we define $\theta(f)$ to be the continuous map $t\mapsto f(t-1)$ on the inverval $[1,2].$

I think this map $\theta$ is an isomorphism of real vector spaces - am I right?

Comment: Yes. All that is left now is to prove it

Comment: @JonathanHole I thought that I can define a map the other way: if $g \in C[1,2],$ then define $\phi(g)$ to be the continuous map $s\mapsto g(s+1)$ on the interval $[0,1]$. Does that work?

Comment: @UtherPendragon Yes, that will work.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos OK great - thank you!

Comment: Of course you have to verify that $\theta$ is a vector space homomorphism (i.e. it's linear) - but that is very easy.  Then the fact that $\phi \circ \theta = \theta \circ \phi = id$ shows that $\theta$ is bijective.